# Kinesis Advantage 2 alt+tab proper macros

Tags: keyboard, kinesis-advantage

In windows when you press alt+tab and you are still holding the alt key - it is a popup window where you can choose window to switch to by pressing Tab key more times (standard behavior).

I have done some remapping for alt key at my KA2, like: left control is now left alt, but it is still not convenient to reach alt+tab combination as you should stretch you fingers.

So I decided why not to do Control+T to behave like Alt+Tab!?
Also, earlier I replaced Delete to Control, so it is right under my thumb and pressing Control+T should be very easy now.

In the config file I added:

```
[delete]>[lctrl]
{lctrl}{t}>{-lalt}{tab}{+lalt}
```

but it behaves like if you press alt+tab **ONCE** - does not show popup window but just switches to last application used.

*so, is there any way to have exactly the same behavior as native alt+tab (with popup) using KA2 macros?*

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late reply...

It happens, because you placed a + in front of the 'lalt' and it means you release that key. If you change it to '{-lalt}{tab}' only, it will do it for you. But. If you do that, the keyboard keeps 'lalt' pushed, so in an app if you hit a key, it will mean 'lalt+key'... For example in FireFox a single 's' will bring up 'History'. It will keep doing it, until you change the 'alt' key's state to 'released', either with a code or pushing the alt key. A solution could be if you build in a wait timer and then release the 'lalt' key using any interval between 1 and 999 millisecond with the syntax {d001} - {d999}.

Comment: so what would be the syntax? I don't have my keyboard with me today to check but I will later...

Comment: `{lctrl}{t}>{-lalt}{tab}`   
Same as what you had originally, but remove the `{+lalt}` from the end